# NppExec in Notepad++ not handling sys.stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++, nppexec

I am having trouble getting NppExec to handle this bit of code:

```
import sys
for inString in sys.stdin :
    print(inString)
```

When I type into the console nothing happens, and I have to terminate the process. I get a message that the process is still running. When I run the program from Powershell it works as expected. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Btw. please accept answers if they solved your issue

Comment: It didn't really fix it. If I hot Ctrl z once nothing happens. If I hit it a bunch it will run it many times. I just ended up using command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Run the file, type your inputs and tape <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> closes the standard input (stdin) by sending [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).